# GetQueuedCompletionStatus hang

Tags: winsock, freeze, iocp

I am tryign to find out why my program is freezing and i narrowed it down to GetQueuedCompletionStatus().

All the IOCP threads are frozen and the only blocking call the threads have is GetQueuedCompletionStatus().

Is there any reason that GetQueuedCompletionStatus() would keep blocking forever after about 30mins~6hours of running time even thought there are still customers connected to the associated sockets?

This is a TCP Winsock program which uses IOCP.
The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Thanks.

Thread code:

```
    while (TRUE)
    {
        pClient = NULL;
        pOverlapped = NULL;
        bRet = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, &dwIOLen, (LPDWORD)&pClient, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&pOverlapped, INFINITE);
        if (bRet == true && pClient != NULL && pOverlapped != NULL && pClient->bConnected == true && pClient->bToDisconnect == false)
        {
            if (pOverlapped->bIOMode == 0) // Recv
            {
                if (TryEnterCriticalSection(&pClient->mNetworkReadCSection))
                {
                    pClient->dwSockBuffLength += dwIOLen;

                    // Packet processing here...

                    WSABUF pWSABuf;
                    pWSABuf.buf = (char*)&pClient->mSockBuffer[pClient->dwSockBuffLength];
                    pWSABuf.len = 10000 - pClient->dwSockBuffLength;
                    DWORD dwRecvd;
                    DWORD dwFlags = 0;
                    memset(&pClient->mSockOverlapped, 0x00, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
                    pClient->mSockOverlapped.bIOMode = 0;
                    int iSent = WSARecv(pClient->ClientSocket, &pWSABuf, 1, &dwRecvd, &dwFlags, (WSAOVERLAPPED*)&pClient->mSockOverlapped, NULL);
                    if (iSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        if (WSAGetLastError() == 10053 || WSAGetLastError() == 10054 || WSAGetLastError() == 10058)
                        {
                            //pClient->bToDisconnect = true;
                            //LeaveCriticalSection(&pClient->mNetworkReadCSection);
                            OnDissconnect(pPacketWriter, pClient->iClientID);
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (WSAGetLastError() != 997 &&  WSAGetLastError() != 10004 && WSAGetLastError() != 10038)
                            WriteToFile("IOCPSocketErr.txt", "[%s] Socket Error: %d\n", pClient->szPlayerName, WSAGetLastError());
                    }

                    LeaveCriticalSection(&pClient->mNetworkReadCSection);
                }
                else
                {
                    PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, dwIOLen, (DWORD)pClient, (OVERLAPPED*)pOverlapped);
                }
            }
            else if (pOverlapped->bIOMode == 1) // Send
            {
                dwBytesSent += dwIOLen;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nop, its Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: Then code may be warranted here. GQCS hangs by design (I know that sounds silly) when there is no detected work. Either the socket with the data you think is enrolled on the IOCP is, in fact, not, or something else wicked this way comes. To make sure your GQCS are listening correctly, can you throw in a heartbeat thread (just for testing) that issues a do-nothing PostQCS and see if its picked up? Hope you understood that.

Comment: But theres over 2000 sockets connected and IOCP says nothing... sounds a little weird to check if the threads works or not, obviously they do not.

Comment: I have attached a debugger and paused the program, but for some reason the debugger doesn't break anywhere, so i assume that the threads are all blocked in GetQueuedCompletionStatus().
Could there be any bug that make GetQueuedCompletionStatus() hangs infinitely after a few hours of runtime?

Comment: I've not seen such a bug, but I normally don't use IOCP with sockets in both async and sync-mode like you are. I'm currently coding up a small server/client test (not just for your benefit, I will use it later myself) to see if I can replicate this. You would think a bug in GQCS would be well known if that were the case. Something else is missing.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a bug in your code.

I've been working with IOCP and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` for over 10 years now and I've never seen an issue with it on any platform.

For a start, the commented out `LeaveCriticalSection(&pClient->mNetworkReadCSection);` above the disconnect will leave your socket locked after this error...

Personally I prefer to see the error constants used rather than magic numbers, it's hard for me to see exactly which errors you are 'handling' here.

I expect that you're ending up in a situation where you have no I/O operations pending, and so you have no activity on your IOCP threads. You could maintain a counter for debug purposes which you increment when you issue an I/O operation and decrement when it completes, also increment it when you post your own completions to the port. This would then help you see if you have any I/O operations pending when you break into your hung program. Remember to increment the counter BEFORE you issue the operation (and decrement it if the operation failed) rather than issuing it after as otherwise the counter may go negative if the completion occurs before the increment.

Comment: I've added logs before and after each API call in the thread to make sure again which one is the problematic.
If its really GetQueuedCompletionStatus() i will then implement the counter check and let you know.
Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation correctly you can have a case where GetQueuedCompletionStatus returns false and pOverlapped is not NULL.  Perhaps you should test for and handle this case.